# Outlook 2010 Custom-Field won't retain leading zeros (0)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I need a field that is 4 digits long but i can't get a field to retain the leading 0s when the numbers are below 4 digits.

i.e 0001 is displayed and stored as 1. I need it to display and store as 0001.

The variable that gets stored into the custom field has the correct 0001 value, but Outlook only stores and displays 1.

I changed the field to text type, made no difference. Rather annoying.

Any suggestions

Comment: Did you really change the field *type* to text, or just the display format?

Answer (score 0):

This is true for numbers without specific format, but text fields retain all characters intact. This is strange that this is not working for you. Try to create a new text field and fill it with zeroes. It has to work!